# How do I get "fade chips" for the event Unleashed Punishment?

Tags: apex-legends, mobile

In this new Unleashed Punishment event, you need Fade Chips to unlock parts of the legend story. I don't know where these chips can be found. Where can I get these chips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit confusing on how to get, but what I read was you can only get one per day, from loot cannisters. You need to play 11 days to get the Fade Skin.